# tkinter Photoimage no such file or directory

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with `PhotoImage` in `tkinter`. It shows me an error when I execute my `.py` that I don't understand:

```
PS C:\Users\Hector\Desktop\python-course> & C:/Users/Hector/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Hector/Desktop/python-course/first_gui/first_gui.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Hector\Desktop\python-course\first_gui\first_gui.py", line 8, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
  File "C:\Users\Hector\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Hector\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4009, in __init__
   self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "logo.png": no such file or directory
```

And this is my code:

```
from tkinter import * 
window= Tk() #crea la ventana y se le asigna a la variable window

window.geometry("720x720")
window.title("First GUI")
window.config(background="#5cfcff")

photo = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
window.iconphoto(True, photo)

window.mainloop() #ejecuta la ventana en pantalla
```

[Here is the proof that I have the image and the `.py` in the same folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phZdA.png)

Comment: Do you know what `cwd` means? For your code to work, the path you run python script must be same as the project directory, you can check this with `import os; print(os.getcwd())` and this should return the project folder

Comment: From the traceback, the working directory is `python-course`, but the script and image are inside `python-course/first_gui/`.

Comment: @Hector Vicente. Your code is working.

Answer (score 0):

The photo needs to either be in the same directory as python, or you can write the full path name in place of "logo.png". So it would look something like "C://path/to/my/file/logo.png".

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if OP used: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "logo.png")`? That way even if OP moves the script and the image to a new folder the code will still work.

Comment: It would indeed. I was debating on if I should mention that or not.

Comment: I don’t think tkinter looks in the folder where python is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the predefined `__file__` variable to determine the what directory the script file is in and then use the to create the path to the image file.

```
import os
from tkinter import *

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # nombre de directorio de este script

window = Tk() #crea la ventana y se le asigna a la variable window

window.geometry("720x720")
window.title("First GUI")
window.config(background="#5cfcff")

photo = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(script_dir, "logo.png"))
window.iconphoto(True, photo)

window.mainloop() #ejecuta la ventana en pantalla
```

Answer (score 0):

```
icon = PhotoImage(file = "icon/emblemsystem_93495.png") # use a png
mw.iconphoto(False, icon) # mw mean mainwindow , change this for your case
```

make sure to copy the right path from your directory. if you want insert an image far away from your app make sure your slashes looks like this = "/" not this way "\ "<--